# Castle Monorail in Webhosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, castle-monorail

Is there any body can help me.

how to run my web running well in web hosting, i'm developed using Castle Monorail MVC, i tested in free web hosting (www.somee.com), but why .castle extension cannot read, even i configure manually in web config, and so my friend told me to change to .ashx extension because web hosting doesn't support other extension and ashx it's default extension in .net.

i try adding like this in web config :

`<add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="Castle.MonoRail.Framework.MonoRailHttpHandlerFactory, Castle.MonoRail.Framework" />`

but it's still not work, so i changed to this :

`<add verb="*" path="*.ashx" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.ashx" type="Castle.MonoRail.Framework.MonoRailHttpHandlerFactory, Castle.MonoRail.Framework" />`

but it's still cannot run, please any body help me how to configure that, or do i must try in another web hosting??

Answer (score 0):

Try just adding this:

```
<add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="Castle.MonoRail.Framework.MonoRailHttpHandlerFactory, Castle.MonoRail.Framework" />
```